# Телеграммбот Вопрос-Ответ

Tags: python, aiogram

Я начинающий программист Python, пишу бота на aiogram для собеседований.
Суть должна быть такова, приходят вопросы из бд в чат и интервьюеромый отвечает на них видеосообщением которые также сохраняются в бд.
Но вот в чем проблема, не могу придумать как вытаскивать вопросы по одному, при запросе в sqlite, можно вытащить все разом или просто первый, сложности добавляет еще то что конечное количество вопросов будет всегда меняться. Пока мысль только организовать через машину состояний, чтобы запоминать предыдущий вопрос, чтоб можно было вызвать следующий.
Но думаю есть решение изящнее и проще.

Comment: Вы же сохраняете ответы на вопросы, значит читайте первый вопрос, на который еще нет ответа `select * from question q where not exists (select 1 from answer a where a.question_id = q.id) order by q.id limit 1`

Comment: Можно ли это как то организовать через fetchone в цикле? Чтобы приходил вопрос, потом человек отвечал, потом вызываем следующий вопрос и т.д.